# MSSQL - OVER, ROW_NUMBER() and ORDER BY error

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I'm trying to make a query that outputs a list with the company data and the number of Products and Discounts of each Company and order by product_count.
Also i need to limit the output to groups of 30 rows

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE Product_Comp_id = Comp_id
    ) as product_count, (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Discount WHERE Disc_Comp_id = Comp_id
    ) as discount_count , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY product_count ASC
    ) AS RowNum FROM Company
) AS finalTable WHERE finalTable.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 30
```

But i get this error

> Invalid column name 'product_count'.

Table Structure

```
Products
    |-Product_id
    |-Product_Name
    |-Product_Description
    |-Product_Comp_id

Discount
    |-Disc_id
    |-Disc_Name
    |-Disc_Comp_id
    |-Disc_Ammount

Company
    |-Comp_id
    |-Comp_Name
    |-Comp_Address
```

Comment: Provide the table structure to help you solve the question~

Comment: You have to try to put product_count in out of your select statment.you have to use it in parent statment cuase you created it in child select statment.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: MSSQL Server @jarlh bad tag

Comment: @JacobH i have the alias, line 4 `) as product_count, (`

Comment: And bad title, as it says MYSQL.

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer i can't see why you need that.. but there you have it

Comment: Please provide sample data and what you want the output to look like.  What is limited to 30 rows?  What constitutes a group?

Comment: @RaymondNijland: those aren't "MSSQL functions". Window functions are defined in the SQL standard and have been part of e.g. Oracle for over 15 years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional level of subquery to give you product_count.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY product_count ASC) AS RowNum
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE Product_Comp_id = Comp_id) as product_count, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Discount WHERE Disc_Comp_id = Comp_id) as discount_count
        FROM Company
    ) C
) AS finalTable WHERE finalTable.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 30
```

Comment: Thanks!! This was what i was looking for.